# Power amplifiers and maximum output amplitude

Tags: power

In the following circuit, what would be the maximum sinusoidal output voltage amplitude \$V_{omax}\$ which would yield a symmetrical sine wave without distortions when no load is connected?
I know the answer is \$3V\$, however, how is it derived? I thought normally \$V_{omax}=V_{cc}-V_{CEsat}\$
[image]

Comment: Trick question? If Q2 is off you can't have a negative swing and you need a load to "give you" ground. Assuming so, you are in a strange case of class A.

Comment: Why do you think \$V_{omax}=V_{cc}-V_{CEsat}\$ applies here ? What would need to be done to make \$V_{o}\$ have its highest value ? Think not in formulas but in this circuit on a bench, what do you apply to make \$V_{omax}\$ at the output ? The same for the lowest voltage.

Comment: @winny I think the crucial information missing in the question regarding Q2 is that it is probably a depletion mode FET. So it does something special when Vgs = 0. No doubt you know what that is but I'm not writing it here (yet) because OP has to figure that out himself.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Oh! I never got around to learn any of these special symbols like depleation mode and substrate contact and just assumed NFET. Well, then it will be a far more interesting problem to solve for OP. :-)

Comment: @winny I don't like that symbol either as it looks to much like a regular (enhancement) NMOS and almost no-one uses depletion NMOS these days. I guessed that it is depletion type from the way it is connected. If it was enhancement type there's no use connecting it like that. I would have used a JFET instead, most circuit designers know a JFET can be used as a *you know what* when gate and source are shorted.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie It's obviously an AC problem.. Do I need therefore to find the gain first?

Comment: Explain to me **why** it is an AC problem. *Maximum sinusoidal* does not sound like **small signal** to me. And not all AC is small signal. Don't call small-signal AC because it isn't.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Well, I assumed it is since the output is sinusoidal

Comment: The shape of the waveform (sine, square, noise or whatever) does not affect the behavior of the circuit. If the signal is **small** we can often assume **small signal behavior** because then we use gm etc. to make things easier. But **only** when the signal is **small**. What they're asking here is how **large** can we make it such that the circuit will not affect the waveform. That has nothing to do with **how** it behaves when the signal **is** small. It has to do with the limitations of the circuit regarding when it cannot process the signal without distorting it.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie I am still not sure how to proceed. The DC difference between Vi and Vo should still be 0.7V. Should I also demand saturation of the CMOS?

Comment: That 0.7 (Vbe) is correct, the upper limit is Vi - Vbe. There is little information regarding the NMOS (I see no CMOS). What is that NMOS doing there anyway ? Indeed some voltage will be across it. How much is unclear from the question.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie Is that information not needed to answer this question?

Comment: You'll need to make resonable assumptions (0.7 V for instance) or give an analytical answer. Do you know the load impedance or can you make assumptions about it?

Comment: @winny The question states R_L->infinity.

Comment: That will simplify it. In real life, I'm thinking this would need to have at least a few uA of load to make it work, but the real problem is on the other end if the spectrum. Have you figured out "the trick"?